# Test local website (in development)

Tags: asp.net, browser, cross-browser, owasp

how can test my website(asp) from Vulnerabilities (OWASP ATTACKS) without program  because it doesn't have IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host it on Local IIS for example. Then access it through the localhost.
In case of using ZAP Tool rember to set it for a browser: 
[ZAP Tool](http://security.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zapbrowsersetup) you can also use Fiddler4. I recommend ZAP :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean it doesnt run?? If you can run your website locally then it will have an IP address, even if its just localhost. If it can be run then you can test it using tools like OWASP ZAP. If you cant run it then it doesnt work so theres no need to test it ;)